# Entity Framework: combining paging with Dynamic LINQ OrderBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I am retriveing some data using Entity Framework like so:

```
var items = GetItems(storeNumber);

Sort(items);

Page(items);

return await items.ToListAsync();
```

I have these private helper methods:

```
private IQueryable<Item> GetItems(string storeNumber)
{
    return _dbContext.Items.Where(x => x.StoreNumber == storeNumber);
}
```

I sort the results using Dynamic LINQ.

```
private void Sort(IQueryable<Item> items, string fieldToSort, string sortDirection)
{
    items = items.OrderBy($"{fieldToSort} {sortDirection}");
}
```

In my Page method I get the exception

> The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

```
private void Page(IQueryable<Item> items, int skip, int take)
{
    items = items.Skip(skip).Take(take);
}
```

I had suspected that the reason for the error was because items needs to be `IOrderedQueryable<Item>` but **there is no overload for the Dynamic LINQ OrderBy which returns** `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.
If I extract the Sort and Page code into the same method, using `var` it's no longer an issue, it infers the type. The problem seems to be using the `IQueryable` interface when sorting and paging. Is there a way I can break up this logic into separate methods but still use Dynamic LINQ for sorting?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is much more trivial. As it's currently, the `Sort` method has no effect (as well `Page` and any LINQ method) because you are not returning the result with applied queryable operator. Consider changing them to a methods returning `IQueryable<Item>`, e.g. `private IQueryable<Item> Sort(...) { return items.OrderBy(...); }`. I don't forget to use the returned result as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev the method is void but I'm passing items as a reference aren't I? I'm setting items to the extended queryable. Maybe I'm confused?

Comment: You are passing a reference to the object into items (which is a local variable in your method). Then you change items (still a local variable), and then your method ends. To achieve what you want (= to change the outer **items**) either you need to use `ref IQueryable<Item> items`, or you need return the local variable `items`. Using `return ...` is by far the most common approach.

Comment: Yes, you pass them as references. But all LINQ methods do not modify the `IQueryable` reference. Instead, they return a **new** reference which needs to be used. If you mean that you assign `items` variable inside the `void` method, you might consider reading about `ref` arguments in C#.

Comment: Yes you are confused. Your Sort function does not Sort you sequence, it only replaces variable item with a new query. Since your4 variable is neither ref, nor out, the items object as supplied by the caller is not changed. It would be different if you did not replace variable items, but changed a property of items

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me. I think my confusion could have been avoided had I just returned the items from the method. At least it's given me the chance to clarify some fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the newly constructed `IQueryable` from the Sort() and the Page() methods, just as you do for GetItems().
If you "rewrite" a parameter value inside a method like this, it has no effect on the value originally passed in to the parameter, because C# uses by-value parameter passing semantics

See this for more reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: I'm passing items as a reference to the Sort and Page methods, or maybe I'm confused?

Comment: It is true that IQueryable is an interface, so it is a reference type, but you are not passing the parameter in by reference. The two are unrelated: you can pass reference types by value (default semantics), or you can do it by reference. You are passing a reference type (so basically a memory address) by value (so a new block is allocated and the reference is copied, but the old one stays untouched when you do the assignment).

See this documentation example for details:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters